# Find the ratio of the area of $\triangle ABC$ to area of $\triangle AOC$

Tags: geometry, vectors

Let $O$ be an interior point of $\triangle ABC$ such that $2\vec{OA}+5\vec{OB}+10\vec{OC}=\vec{0}$.Find the ratio of the area of $\triangle ABC$ to area of $\triangle AOC$.

---

My Attempt:
Let $O$ be the origin and let the position vectors of points $A,B,C$ are $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ respectively.Then $\vec{OA}=\vec{a},\vec{OB}=\vec{b},\vec{OC}=\vec{c}$
$\frac{\text{area of}\triangle ABC}{\text{area of}\triangle AOC}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}|(\vec{a}-\vec{b})\times(\vec{c}-\vec{b})|}{\frac{1}{2}|\vec{a}\times \vec{c}|}=\frac{|\vec{a}\times\vec{b}+\vec{b}\times\vec{c}+\vec{c}\times\vec{a}|}{|\vec{a}\times \vec{c}|}$
But i could not solve further.I am stuck here.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to replace $b$ by some sum of $a$ and $c$?

Comment: Do you mean $\vec{b}=\vec{a}+\vec{c}$?I think they are not equal.

Comment: Indeed they are not, but don't you have $2a+5b+10c=0$?

Comment: @GBQT,thank you for the hint ,sir,i got the answer.